# Diff Checker in days with PHP

Tags: php

```
    $date1 = "2018-10-10";
    $date2 = "2018-11-19";

    $date1 = date_create($date1);
    $date2 = date_create($date2);

    $diff = date_diff($date1,$date2);

    echo $diff;
```

When I try to output `$diff`, it gives me this error:

`Recoverable fatal error: Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\grab.php on line 29`

Help?

Comment: use `var_dump($diff);` to see what it contains, and check the [DateInterval](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using this to echo out the difference between your dates:

```
echo $diff->format("%R%a days");
```

instead of just

```
echo $diff;
```

Comment: Think you were quickest here. Thanks, progx :)

Comment: @michaelmcgurk You can always mark my answer as the correct one :). Thanks

Comment: Thanks again. Marked correct (finally!) :)

Answer (score 1):

call `DateInterval::format()` to get the date difference in string.

```
echo $diff->format('%d days');
```

you can also read the manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php

Answer (score 1):

`date_diff` doesn't return a string but an object which represents the difference. You need call the `format` method on that object.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php#refsect1-datetime.diff-examples

```
$date1 = "2018-10-10";
$date2 = "2018-11-19";

$date1 = date_create($date1);
$date2 = date_create($date2);

$diff = date_diff($date1,$date2);
echo $diff->format('%R%a days');
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
echo $diff->format("%a");
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you, Andrea :)

Comment: you're welcome @michaelmcgurk!